# Consulta en db MySQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, sql

Tengo este problema al conectarme a mi base de datos

```
 <?php
        $cnx=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","itamar123","ingweb","3308");
        mysqli_query($cnx,"set names utf8");
    
                $sNombreCliente=$_POST['sNombreCliente'];
                $sApellidosCliente=$_POST['sApellidosCliente'];
                $sDireccionCliente=$_POST['sDireccionCliente'];
                $sCiudadCliente=$_POST['sCiudadCliente'];
                
                $sql="INSERT INTO md_clientes VALUES('$sNombreCliente,
                                                    '$sApellidosCliente,
                                                    '$sDireccionCliente',
                                                    '$sCiudadCliente')";
                $ejecutar=mysqli_query($cnx,$sql);
                if(!$ejecutar){
                    echo"Hubo algun error";
                }else{
                    echo"Datos guardados correctamente<br><a href='formulario.html'>Volver</a>";
                }                       
            ?>
```

Y me devuelve al ejectuarlo mediante mi formulario html "Hubo algun error"

Quisiera saber que está mal dentro de mi código...

Comment: Bienvenido, considera revisa [ask], especifica cual es el problema por favor, saludos.

Comment: Saludos. Revisa tu `INSERT` falta terminación de cada dato tipo cadena de texto; además si no especificas los campos la BD tomara estos en un orden particular (me parece es como estan declaradas las columnas) si alguna no coincide o su longitud es insuficiente fallará.

Comment: Sí está con el puerto 3308, el problema es que al correrlo mediante mi formulario html conectado a este php, me boto el error que está en la condicional if, que es "Hubo algún error" y no me registra...

Comment: @RobertoLeOr Cómo haría eso, explícame por favor...

Answer (score 1):

```
Prueba a esto

$ejecutar=mysqli_query($cnx,$sql);

if($ejecutar==false){
   echo"Hubo algun error";
}else{
  echo"Datos guardados correctamente<br><a 
  href='formulario.html'>Volver</a>";
}
```

Comment: No me lo solucionó, me arroja el siguiente error
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in C:\laragon\www\examen\phpguardar.php on line 15

Comment: Ya le corregí, aún así me salió ese error...

Comment: Error de Sintaxis : (

Comment: Nueva Solución.

Comment: Me vuelve a mostrar lo mismo,

Hubo algun error

Answer (score 1):

Asumiendo que los datos de conexión y demás pasos/procesos los tengas correctos; lo que observo es tu `sql` esta con errores:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO md_clientes VALUES('$sNombreCliente, /* Aqui falta fin de texto */
                                     '$sApellidosCliente,  /* Aqui falta fin de texto */
                                     '$sDireccionCliente',
                                     '$sCiudadCliente')";
```

debe ser:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO md_clientes VALUES('$sNombreCliente', /* Corregido */
                                     '$sApellidosCliente',  /* Corregido */
                                     '$sDireccionCliente',
                                     '$sCiudadCliente')";
```

Te comento que en caso que el resultado a `mysqli_query` retorne `FALSE` uses [`mysqli_error`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.error.php) para obtener detalle del error (esto en caso que no salga (digamos) en automático el error al momento de su ejecución.

Para ello le sugiero lo siguiente:

```
if($ejecutar===false){
   echo mysqli_error($cnx);
}else{
   echo"Datos guardados correctamente<br><a href='formulario.html'>Volver</a>";
}
```